# Start/pause audio in an embed tag ? (IE8+)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio, embed

I'm creating pages for a small web-based game which must have some background music playing. Those pages should be compatible with most desktop browsers, including IE8 (but we can ignore the mobile browsers).

Of course I'd like to allow the user to stop the music. And this is where it gets tricky.

Here's what I use currently (with jQuery) :

```html
<audio id="main_audio" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" loop="loop">
    <source src="sounds/bgmusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="sounds/bgmusic.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true" src="sounds/bgmusic.mp3" />
</audio>
<div id="controls" class="controls">
    <a id="playpause" class="play">Play/Pause</a>
</div>
<script>
    function isPlaying(audio) {return !audio.paused;}
    var a = document.getElementById('main_audio');
    $('#playpause').on('click', function() {
        if (isPlaying(a)) {
            a.pause();
        } else {
            a.play();
        }
    });
</script>
```

This works fine in all browsers, but IE. (I'm on Windows XP so testing on IE8 currently.)
On IE8, the audio starts playing (which is good) but the controls don't do anything so it's impossible to stop the music (and restart it).

How can I make this script work for IE too? In other word, interact with the embed tag (but only in IE)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try next code:

```
<audio id="main_audio" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" loop="loop">
    <source src="sounds/bgmusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="sounds/bgmusic.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <embed id="main_audio_ie8" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true" src="sounds/bgmusic.mp3" />
</audio>
<div id="controls" class="controls">
    <a id="playpause" class="play">Play/Pause</a>
</div>
<script>
    var isPlaying = function(audio) {return !audio.paused;}
    var a = document.getElementById('main_audio');
    if(!(a.play instanceof Function)){
        a = document.getElementById('main_audio_ie8');
        isPlaying = function(audio) {return audio.playState==2;}
    }
    $('#playpause').on('click', function() {
        if (isPlaying(a)) {
            a.pause();
        } else {
            a.play();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Another variant (code must work if WMPlayer.OCX exist on system; checked on Win2K+IE6SP1+WMP7, WinXP+IE6SP1+WMP9, WinXP+IE8+WMP11):

```
<audio id="main_audio" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" loop="loop" volume="1.0">
    <source src="sounds/bgmusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="sounds/bgmusic.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <object id="main_audio_ie8" classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" style="display:none;"> 
        <param name="URL" value="sounds/bgmusic.mp3" />
        <param name="uiMode" value="invisible" /> 
        <param name="autoStart" value="true" />
        <param name="volume" value="100" />
        <param name="playCount" value="2147483647" /> <!-- (Int32) 2^31-1==2147483647 - maximum allowed count (for 1 second length audio is equals to 68+ years) -->
    </object> 
</audio>
<div id="controls" class="controls">
    <a id="playpause" class="play">Play/Pause</a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
    var isPlaying,a=document.getElementById('main_audio');
    if(a.play instanceof Function)isPlaying=function(audio){return !audio.paused;};
    else{
        a=document.getElementById('main_audio_ie8');
        isPlaying=function(audio){return audio.playState==3;};
        a.play=function(){this.controls.play();}
        a.pause=function(){this.controls.pause();}
    }
    document.getElementById('playpause').onclick=function() {
        if (isPlaying(a)) {
            a.pause();
        } else {
            a.play();
        }
    };
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to try it but it seems promising. :-)

Comment: OK I tried it but it doesn't work. :( After testing I noted two things: 1) isPlaying evaluates to "false", even though the music is playing (autostart). 2) even if I put a.pause() out of the "if", it doesn't seem to have any effect. Actually a.pause() throws an error (Object doesn't support this property or method), while a.play() doesn't. But a.play() doesn't seem to work either (tested with autostart=false)...

Comment: Actually i tried using an alert displaying a.playState and it appears that playState is undefined.

Comment: @s427, Hmm, I tested this on WinXP in IE8 and IE6-IE7 (after replacing jQuery code). All worked. This method uses Windows Media Player ActiveX object for playing audio (in my case, because HTML5 <audio> tag not supported in IE8). In IE8 can be security alert displayed when first used _'This website wants to run the following add-on: "Windows Media Player Core" from "Microsoft Corporation"'_. Inside _`isPlaying`_ `typeof audio.play` or `typeof audio.pause` must be equals to _`unknown`_.

Comment: That's strange. I don't see any warning (except the javascript error). Maybe my version of IE misses some component? Here's the simplest test case I could make using your proposed code: https://cirrus.hsolutions.ch/teststemp/dk_tdm7s/test.php Can you tell me if it's working for you in IE?

Comment: @s427, I dont know why, but your link opened only in my IE9 or FF. On PC's with WinXP and IE6-8 (real PC's and virtual PC's) your page not opened (I dont know why). But if tested in IE9 browser in IE8 mode then browser first asked _'This website wants to run the following add-on: "Windows Media Player Core" from "Microsoft Corporation"'_ If accepting then all works.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your help. Other people have told me it works fine in IE9, so that's a good thing already. :-) I guess I'll just use another method for playing sounds for IE8 (maybe remove the element from the DOM and reattach it when needed).

Comment: @s427, Added second variant. You can check it if you want. As I know when using this method add-on blocker is not displayed.

Comment: Second variant. 
Windows 7, IE8.
Message: **'null' is null or not an object** on `a.play=function(){`

Comment: @indapublic IE8 in Win7? In Win7 minimum version of IE is IE9?! IE9 supports HTML5 <audio>

Comment: @AndrewD. Hm. Windows 8.1 & IE 11.0. Audio played using `object` not `source`. Is it correct?

Comment: @AndrewD. Ok, I got it. Windows 7 & IE 8 is not working because it is Windows N. Is it possible to use Flash in this case?

Comment: @indapublic I dont know about Windows N edition and flash. To prevent using `<object>` in IE9 and greater try to use `<!--[if lt IE 9]>  <object ...> ... </object> <![endif]-->`

Comment: First proposition autoplay the sound on IE8 (didn't work with OGG). But the 'click' behavior to toggle pause doesn't work.