# Reduce delays after playing a sound onclick?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying a make a website (using JavaScript) that has buttons and if someone clicks on it, it plays a sound.

But the thing is when I clicked on the button, it waits (I guess loading) for few seconds and then plays the sound.  If the sound says "hello" and someone constantly clicks on it, I want it to play "he-he-he-he-he-hello".

The buttons are .pngs and I also have a animation of pressing buttons.

Each code calls four functions. so is this an efficiency problem? Can someone suggest me better method?

```
<html>
    <body>
<title>Title</title>

 <head>
        <style type="text/css">
         body{
         background: url('noisy_grid.png');
         background-repeat: repeat;
         }
        </style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
// PRELOADING IMAGES
if (document.images) {
 btn1_down=new Image(); btn1_down.src="img1_down.png"; 
 btn1_up  =new Image(); btn1_up.src  ="imag1_up.png"; 

 btn2_down=new Image(); btn2_down.src="img2_down.png"; 
 btn2_up  =new Image(); btn2_up.src  ="img2_up.png"; 

 btn3_down=new Image(); btn3_down.src="imag3_down.png"; 
 btn3_up  =new Image(); btn3_up.src  ="img3_up.png"; 

  btn4_down=new Image(); btn4_down.src="img4_down.png"; 
 btn4_up  =new Image(); btn4_up.src  ="img4_up.png"; 

  btn5_down=new Image(); btn5_down.src="img5_down.png"; 
 btn5_up  =new Image(); btn5_up.src  ="img5_up.png"; 

  btn6_down=new Image(); btn6_down.src="img6_down.png"; 
 btn6_up  =new Image(); btn6_up.src  ="img6_up.png"; 

}

// EVENT HANDLERS
function pressButton(btName) {
 if (document.images)
  eval('document.'+btName+'.src='+btName+'_down.src');
}
function releaseButton(btName) {
 if (document.images)
  eval('document.'+btName+'.src='+btName+'_up.src');
}

function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
    "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}

 -->
    </script>
 </head>

 <span id="dummy"></span>
<center>
<br>
 <a onMouseDown="pressButton('btn1');" 
      onMouseUp="releaseButton('btn1');" 
      onMouseOut="releaseButton('btn1');" 
      onclick="playSound('sound1.mp3');"><img name=btn1 src="img1_up.png" /></a>

<a onMouseDown="pressButton('btn2');" 
      onMouseUp="releaseButton('btn2');" 
      onMouseOut="releaseButton('btn2');" 
      onclick="playSound('sound2.mp3');"><img name=btn2 src="img2_up.png" /></a>


<a onMouseDown="pressButton('btn3');" 
      onMouseUp="releaseButton('btn3');" 
      onMouseOut="releaseButton('btn3');" 
      onclick="playSound('sound3.mp3');"><img name=btn3 src="img3_up.png" /></a>
</br>
 <br>
<a onMouseDown="pressButton('btn4');" 
      onMouseUp="releaseButton('btn4');" 
      onMouseOut="releaseButton('btn4');" 
      onclick="playSound('sound4.mp3');"><img name=btn4 src="img4_up.png" /></a>


<a onMouseDown="pressButton('btn5');" 
      onMouseUp="releaseButton('btn5');" 
      onMouseOut="releaseButton('btn5');" 
      onclick="playSound('sound5.mp3');"><img name=btn5 src="img5_up.png" /></a>

<a onMouseDown="pressButton('btn6');" 
      onMouseUp="releaseButton('btn6');" 
      onMouseOut="releaseButton('btn'6);" 
      onclick="playSound('sound6.mp3');"><img name=btn6 src="img6_up.png" /></a>
</br>

</center>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not included the button and audio code which is really the only thing relevant to this question. The button-loading functionality is unlikely to be part of the problem. More likely that you are only loading the audio content on click when it should be loaded directly with the page. Please include all relevant code.

Comment: Everytime you are embedding the sound it will need to reload, so you will most likely always get a delay, you will have to preload the sound - I would also suggest using a player like SoundManager2.

Comment: why not preloading the sounds also? use embed tag with unique id, then document.geElementById("unique").play()

Comment: jb// Thanks for the comments. This is everything I have. I said buttons but it's really an image that when you click on it, it changes to an different image and goes back to the original image if you unclick it. I'm not sure what you mean by audio code. playSound function is the only code that plays the audio. And how I make the audio content s loaded directly?

Comment: Shannon// As I said I don't really have any experience with web scripting so I'll do a search on that.

Comment: Crisim Il Numenoreano//I've tried that but I couldn't figure out a way to do it with onclick,onMouseDown,onMouseUp etc working

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953656/start-pause-audio-in-an-embed-tag-ie8) could help you

Answer (score 0):

Wow, is that really necessary? Eval? Embed? *REALLY?*

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Title</title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        body{ 
            background: url('noisy_grid.png'); 
            background-repeat: repeat; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <center id="container"></center> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var images = {}, pressButton, releaseButton, playSound, i, a, aud, img,
                container = document.getElementById('container');
            // preload images
            for( i=1; i<=6; i++) {
                (images[i+'d'] = new Image()).src = "img"+i+"_down.png";
                (images[i+'u'] = new Image()).src = "img"+i+"_up.png";
            }

            // event handlers
            pressButton = function(btn) {
                btn.firstChild.src = images[btn.btnid+'d'].src;
            }
            releaseButton = function(btn) {
                btn.firstChild.src = images[btn.btnid+'u'].src;
            }
            playSound = function(btn) {
                btn.nextSibling.play();
            }

            for( i=1; i<=6; i++) {
                a = document.createElement('a');
                img = document.createElement('img');
                aud = document.createElement('audio');

                if( !aud.canPlayType || aud.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") == ""
                          || aud.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") == "no") {
                    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support MP3.");
                    return;
                }

                a.onmousedown = function() {pressButton(this);};
                a.onmouseup = a.onmouseout = function() {releaseButton(this);};
                a.onclick = function() {playSound(this);};
                a.btnid = i;
                img.src = images[i+'u'].src;
                aud.src = "sound"+i+".mp3";

                container.appendChild(a);
                a.appendChild(img);
                container.appendChild(aud);
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have completely re-written your code to get it out of last milennium and into the present day. If you need help understanding how it works, let me know with a specific question.

Comment: I honestly don't understand everything completely. I see you have variables and loops to remove duplicates and I have ideas what child/sibling properties do but where did windows come from? Also I tested the code out but it not doing anything when I click on the image.

Comment: I edited the answer shortly after posting it. You may be using the older version of the code, which did have some errors. It should work now.

Comment: oh okay I see some changes made on code. I googled windows and I'm guessing it's a global object of javascript. I've tested the code again in different browsers and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks you

Comment: `window` is *the* global object. In your old code, `window.btn1_down` would be the image that you defined in the `btn1_down` variable. The code I have given has no global variables, which is generally considered a good thing.

Comment: I have one more question. Right now a.onclick is calling the playSound function but is there a way to restart this while it's still executing? Like when I click on a button it plays a sound but when I click on it again (while it's still playing the sound) it plays from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, you can add `btn.nextSibling.currentTime = 0;` right before the `btn.nextSibling.play()`.