# how to make video tag and pause and stop methods working on ie8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

How to make video tag and its major methods working on ie8?

I tried with html5media javascript library. but it is not providing play/pause controlling on the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [nice project - Video for Everybody](http://v4e.thewikies.com) for a nice generator of HTML5 tags.

Comment: Thanks, Its great but I need to pause the video from javascript. can you help me regarding? Is it possible on IE8 using only javascript?

Comment: i think i've fount the answer from another topic: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953656/start-pause-audio-in-an-embed-tag-ie8

Comment: found*  
sorry for my syntax mistake)

Comment: Thanks again @BordiMan. Is mozilla supporting the same which is there in the topic. for me its not working in Mozilla. Can you suggest me any help.?

Comment: in Mozila? It can not be.. Maybe you set something wrong in formats. Here is the links of properties that u must set to mozila:
 1) http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/viewing-html5-audio-and-video  
2)https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is not fully supported html5. you'r better using flash