# Audio tag alternatives for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to create a button which plays and pauses audio when clicked. This works fine in Google Chrome and newer browsers although I need it to support IE 8 as well. I've tried using `<embed>` tags and have changed the triggers to fit the embedded audio but it still doesn't play or pause in IE 8? I'd like to use jQuery if possible.

**HTML**

```
<audio id="sound" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-snd').click(function() {
            if ($('#sound').prop("paused") == false) {
                $('#sound').trigger("pause");
                $('.toggle-snd').text('Play interview');
                $('.toggle-snd').toggleClass('active2');
            } else {
                $('#sound').trigger("play");
                $('.toggle-snd').text('Pause interview');
                $('.toggle-snd').toggleClass('active2');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start/pause audio in an embed tag ? (IE8+)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953656/start-pause-audio-in-an-embed-tag-ie8)

Comment: If you are building a net-new feature today you really need to ask if supporting IE8 is really necessary. AFAIR all IE8 support from Microsoft drops this July when Win2003 EOL kicks in.

Comment: @scunliffe It's for viewing on a school network... they only have IE 8 unfortuntately :S

Comment: @JoshuaMcEwen I guess I'm saying you likely want to find out how soon this network is being upgraded... because your design constraint **should** be going away soon and quite possibly before you ship.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/), a cross-browser javascript wrapper for the html5 audio tag.