# How to pause HTML 5 Video player using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, url, video, pause

Well, the title may be sounds easy, but what i want is to do the same thing from browser address bar (my page contains many  videos ).
i tried

```
   javascript:videoelement=document.getElementById("vid1");videoelement.pause();
```

It doesn't works anyway.

suppose my code is

```
<html>
<body>
<embed src="https://myaudio.mp3" autoplay="false" height="100" width="300">
</body>
</html>
```

how can i pause/paly the player?

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("embed").pause();
```

^^^ not working

Comment: Can you explain **"the same thing from browser address bar"**

Comment: i want to pause HTML 5 Video player using JavaScript from the browser address bar (js injection )

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `#` from the element name like so:

```
javascript:videoelement=document.getElementById("vid1");videoelement.pause();
```

You are already using the `getElementById` function so you don't need it.

Comment: sorry, i was trying the same...(question edited now)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a jQuery/CSS ID selector when what you wanted was using vanilla javascript.

You are trying to select an element with ID "#vid1", such as:
    `<video id="#vid1">`

Just remove the "#" from `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Audio/Video DOM pause() Method:

The play() method starts playing the current audio or video.

Tip: Use the [pause()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp) method to pause the current audio/video.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<embed src="https://myaudio.mp3" autoplay="false" height="100" width="300">
</body>
</html>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953656/start-pause-audio-in-an-embed-tag-ie8

Comment: bro we can do it in plain js. but what i want is to do the same from url address bar.